# Cannot create JPA Facet: "project facet jpt.jpa could not be found"

Tags: eclipse, jpa, configuration, facet

I have a maven project in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. But when I go enable JPA facet, I cannot choose JPA (there is no JPA option). Have I forgotten to include some dependency?

[image]

I've installed the following Maven dependencies: eclipslink-2.5.-RC1.jar, javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar, and mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar.

I get the following warning on my project:

> Implementation of project facet jpt.jpa could not be found. Functionality will be limited.

**UPDATE**: I have the Dali Java Persistence Tools installed.

[image]

Comment: JPA Support != JPA Support SDK, try installing JPA support.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Aren't the above plugins JPA support?

Comment: Yes, but JPA Support SDK is a different package than JPA Support, entirely possible it behaves differently. @AllieCat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JPA facet is not dependent on what is in your pom.xml. Check to make sure you have these plugins installed (The ones highlighted in blue).

Help -> Install New Software... -> What is already installed?

[image]

If they're missing you can find the plugin here: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I already have those installed... I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The JPA facet is something that is suppose to be baked into Eclipse for Java EE developers. What version of eclipse are you using? I have Juno installed on my mac that I use for android dev and the facet appears there. It also appears on my work computer with the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse installed. I also use WTP-M2E + Eclipselink and never had to install anything regarding JPA. I simply checked the JPA facet, put the Eclipselink dependency in my pom.xml and was good to go. I would try deleting eclipse completely and downloading the newest copy.

Comment: I just downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse and now everything is fine. I don't know how I messed up my old copy so much!