# Not able to create or convert a project in to JPA Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, facet

I am trying to convert one project to JPA enabled project by assigning "JPA Facet" from  `preferences > Project` Facets in eclipse.

But, there is no option to select "JPA Facets".

[image]

After analysis, i found that i am even not able to create a new JPA project with eclipse, i am having.

[image]

I am using eclipse JUNO. I think, i am missing something in configuration.
I have tried installing eclipselink<>.jar to userlibrary configuration. But, it is not working.

Reason which i found is also mentioned in below duplicate question.
[Cannot create JPA Facet: “project facet jpt.jpa could not be found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299667/cannot-create-jpa-facet-project-facet-jpt-jpa-could-not-be-found)

In this also, it is mentioned that update to new eclipse. But, is there any way to find out, what is messed up in existing eclipse.

Comment: Possibly you need the "Eclipse for JavaEE developers" release before you have that facet. Not that you need that facet to use JPA in a project by the way, I've never seen the point of it.

Comment: As @Gimby pointed out, which distribution of Juno have you downloaded?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Gimby, Magnilex , I am using **"Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers"**,  Version: Juno Service Release 1 , Build id: 20121004-1855. Is there a way to update this release to JavaEE developers as i have other projects too running on same eclipse.

Comment: No idea where you got that build, it doesn't exist on the download site: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr2 . I'm going to guess its just the regular JavaEE package, so then you should already have the facet. What type of project did you create? When you right click on the project and you highlight the **configure** menu option, is there perhaps some sort of JPA option in there?

Comment: @Gimby , I have checked that option. Right click on project. Go to configure, there i couldn't find option named as JPA.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. I'd very much advise you to update. And do note that your current projects are not lost because you do that, you can simply open the workspace in the new Eclipse (I would make a backup as the most recent Eclipse will convert the workspace to a new format). You don't even have to throw away your old Eclipse installation, you can just unzip a second copy somewhere else and experiment with it.

Comment: @Gimby, thanks for your suggestions. I will update eclipse version from "Juno" to "Kepler". After investigations, i found that eclipse was pointing to eclipse web tools.

Comment: I got a chance to solve this issue. I have installed eclipse from scratch and it works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Here is what I did and it worked:

1. Go to help -> install new software
2. In work with select *Neon - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon*
   (in my case)
3. In here you find *"Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development"*.
   Open it!
4. Just installed everything that included the title *"JPA"*
5. Click finish, install, restart Eclipse

Now try again to find your facet!