# JPA Tools Menu Missing From Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jpa

I have created a [Spring Boot application](http://start.spring.io/) (Maven project) with JPA and SQL Server dependencies. When I open the project in Eclipse and right-click on my project in the Project Explorer, I do not seem the *JPA Tools* option.

The JPA section is also missing in the Project Facets.

**Eclipse Version**: Oxygen.2 Release 4.7.2

**Java Version**: 1.8

**OS**: macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4

[image]

Comment: Oxygen.2 Release 4.7.2 is a *version*, it tells us nothing about whether the JPA Tools are actually installed. So, are they?

Comment: @nitind but they are not found in the Marketplace either. How do I add them is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you should add JPA facet to your project.

Project -> context menu -> property -> project facets -> JPA

[image]

Then click further configuration available..

[image]

Then  you set DB connection  by clicking add connection.. Link
Choose connection profile types

[image]

Then set connection details

[image]

Comment: check this page if you use oracle db -->  https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781782160960/1/ch01lvl1sec12/adding-the-jpa-facet

Comment: JPA option is not appearing in my eclipse ide project facets.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct, but if you're missing the JPA Facet in your project properties, you should do this

Go to help -> install new software

Search for JPA

Select Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development and install

Restart Eclipse

Also see [Not able to create or convert a project in to JPA Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111999/not-able-to-create-or-convert-a-project-in-to-jpa-project)