# How to generate DDL from entities in eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create the ddl from entities in a spring boot project. I am using eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0). Ideally, I am looking for something similar to the JPA Buddy plugin in intellij where you can right click on an entity and it gives the option "Show ddl ...". Most solutions I look at assume you already have a "JPA" project, I don't, mine is a Spring Boot Project. Next, some solutions talk about adding JPA facet to the project. When I select properties for the project, there is no such thing as "Project Facet", but there is "Project Natures" which currently includes "Java" and "Maven Nature" for me. And when I try to add a nature, the only options I see are " Gradle Project Nature" and "WikiTextNature", so I assumed I have to install a JPA specific software like mentioned here [JPA Tools Menu Missing From Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817803/jpa-tools-menu-missing-from-eclipse), but could not find that specific one. I didn't see any obvious looking candidate, I tried the "Hibernate Tools (Helios) 3.4.x" and the "Hibernate Tools (Indigo) 3.4.x" but none worked. I also tried adding the required properties in the properties file as mentioned here, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-generate-db-schema, but that too did not work.

Comment: Please show some relevant code like the entities, pom.xml/build.gradle file, application properties.

Comment: [Generating tables from entities](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks007.htm)